# Python, facebook-sdk graphAPI returning empty dataset

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I have written a python script to get the feed info of a user.

```
try:
    # Init graphAPI with short-lived token
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token_fb)
    # Exchange short-lived-token to long-lived
    long_token = graph.extend_access_token(app_id, app_secret)
    print(long_token)
    # Init graphAPI with long-lived token
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(long_token['access_token'])
    profile = graph.get_object("me")
    print('profile : '+str(profile))
    posts=graph.get_connections(profile['id'],'feed')
    print(posts['data'])
    return posts
except facebook.GraphAPIError:
    return None
```

I am getting empty dataset whether I try to retrieve posts or feed. I used the access token in Graph API explorer to get feed and it does come back with data, so the user access token has permissions too. what could be the problem in the script? I am just trying to get all posts posted on my wall.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what you're passing `get_object()`. You should instead be passing it something like `profile = graph>get_object(id=MY_USER_ID)` where `MY_USER_ID` is a string representing your unique user id for Facebook.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but the profile is already getting the id and name in a directory like, {‘name’:’ my name’, ‘id’:’profile id’}. This ID is what I am passing in connections. Also, just wondering if I pass the unique id in get_objects, how do I retrieve id in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, was using the wrong application’s access token. Provided permissions to the app and got the results back.